# How to Calculate Conditional Correlation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, correlation

Here is my screenshot and link to the spreadsheet.  I am trying to calculate the correlation between number of passes students take and their grades, but only for those with greater than 60% attendance.  I am not sure what is wrong with my formula.
[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k5zV4WeA2-sU3lYAm32J1xsR_XEl3wx8Ffj4rJk2Q4Y/edit?usp=sharing)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your formula, including that you are using range references (e.g., "B2:B98") where QUERY only calls for "B"; but rather than telling you what is wrong, I'll just share what should be *right* as well as easier for you:

`=ArrayFormula(CORREL(FILTER(B2:B,A2:A>0.6),FILTER(C2:C,A2:A>0.6)))`

If you want to stick with QUERY:

`=ArrayFormula(CORREL(QUERY(A2:C,"Select B WHERE A > 0.6"),QUERY(A2:C,"Select C WHERE A > 0.6")))`

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked.  I would love to know if there is a way to use the query function for this.

Comment: See my reply post update. Please take a moment to mark the reply post as "Best Answer." This allows the contributor community here to see from the main listings page which posts have already been fully resolved; and it allows future site visitors to most quickly find relevant answers. Thanks.

Comment: Aside from using ranges instead of column references, your second `0.6` was enclosed in single quotes for some reason, while the first was (correctly) not.

Comment: It looks like you may have upvoted my post. However, there should be a checkmark that you can check beside the post as well, which will mark it "Best Answer." Please look for and click that checkmark. Thanks.